# Reading integers from a file in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to read integers from a file in Java and display the highest value, but I'm having a difficult time thinking about it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MyFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String filename;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the name of the file.");

        filename = in.nextLine();
        File file = new File("myFile.txt");
        Scanner inputfile = new Scanner(file);
        while(inputfile.hasNext())
        {
            int compare = inputfile.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

The file is simply called myFile.txt and has the integers 23, 34, 45, and 2.

Comment: Please ask a specific question or indicate what you have tried that isn't working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we can't help you to think about something.  You will need to explain to us what you are actually having problems with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you require to find the highest value from the file, you can do:

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
while(inputfile.hasNext()) {
     int compare = inputfile.nextInt();
     if (compare > max){
         max = compare;
     }
}
System.out.println("highest value:"+ max);
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: This works beautifully, thank you!

Comment: @TwentyGaugeHigh: You are welcome. Please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable `maxValue`. Initialize this value with the file value in file. Loop through rest of the file comparing the newly read value with the `maxValue`. If the newly read value is greater than the `maxValue`. Assign `maxValue` to that value.

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc states:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches whitespace. Your file should contain

```
23 34 45 2
```

without commas in between